# Is it a bad practice to use loop with delay in coroutine to replace the TimerTask

Tags: android, kotlin, mutex, kotlin-coroutines

I am using a while loop with a `delay()` inside in a coroutine.

```
scope.launch {
 while(true) {
  // some code here
  delay()
 }  
}
```

The idea here is to vary the delay time dynamically and to put a `mutex.withLock` in the code block.
Will this approach cause any issue to my app or shall I go with the TimerTask.

Comment: The code as shown has no issues with it. If the coroutine (or its CoroutineScope) is cancelled, it will appropriately finish at the next time it suspends in your `delay()` call. Note that your coroutine delay is an interval between each repeat of the "task", but with TimerTask, I think the time interval is steady and includes the time spent performing the task (if I recall correctly).

Comment: That last half of @Tenfour04 comment is talking about "fixed delay" versus "fixed rate" execution for periodic tasks. Your coroutine code is "fixed delay", which is similar to if you scheduled a `TimerTask` with [`Timer#schedule(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)), if I'm not mistaken ([`Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) being the other option).

Comment: But I got to know that a loop inside a coroutine is generally considered a bad idea, particularly when if you are waiting for an event happen. I also wanted to know if there are any added benefits of using TimerTask() over this.